# Seeking Assistance with Now Playing Screen on CarPlay using flutter_carplay

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, carplay

I am currently working on developing a Flutter audio application with CarPlay integration, utilizing the flutter_carplay module and flutter_radio. I am facing a challenge in implementing the Now Playing Screen.

I have gone through the documentation and came across an interesting pull request (https://github.com/oguzhnatly/flutter_carplay/pull/22/commits/6f15f6666286f99b4aa67427c5c3c659cfcfd690) that seems to contain a specific modification for Now Playing. I tried to integrate it, but I am not able to get the screen at work.

Can someone help me with how to integrate this in a project? I can get contact with CarrPlay with the normal templates, but can not get a now playing screen.

I appreciate any help I can get, and any examples or code snippets would be highly beneficial. Thank you in advance for your time and expertise!

Comment: Is there anybody who can point me in the right direction?